# Multiplication of numbers whose valuese are between 0 and 1

Tags: products

Given a set of numbers $Q = \{q_1,q_2,\cdots,q_n\} \subseteq (0,1]$.

The product $\prod\limits_{q_i\in Q}{q_i}$ gets smaller and smaller when the cardinally $|Q|$ increases.

That is, $\prod\limits_{q_i\in Q}{q_i} \geq \prod\limits_{q_i\in Q^*}{q_i}$ where $Q \subseteq Q^*$, where $Q$ and $Q^*$ are defined like above.

Is there a name for this mathematical property?

Comment: Maybe you are interested in contractions (when you inteprete your question as iteration of linear functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see this as a special case of monotonicity, or order-reversing:

Let $\mathscr{P}$ be the set of finite sequences $(q_1,\ldots,q_n)$, with $0<q_i\leq 1$. It comes with a natural order, given by initial subsequences, i.e., $(q_1,\ldots,q_n)\leq(q_1,\ldots,q_n,q_{n+1},\ldots,q_m)$.

We have a function $\pi:\mathscr{P}\to[0,1]$, given by $\pi(q_1,\ldots,q_n)=\prod_{i=1}^nq_i$. The property you stated means that
$$Q_1\leq Q_2\implies \pi(Q_1)\geq\pi(Q_2)$$
which means that the function $\pi$ is order-reversing.

See [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_theory#Functions_between_orders) for more details on order structures.

---

**Remark:** I chose to consider sequences instead of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ so that we can have repeated numbers among the $q_i$'s. You could do similar analysis with finite subsets of $(0,1]$ and again obtain an order-reversing function $\pi:\{\text{finite subsets of }(0,1]\}\to(0,1]$.